# SSH tunneling doesn't work when use external ip address or external name

Tags: ssh, networking

I'm trying to set up an ssh tunnel from my desktop machine (192.168.1.2) to my raspberry pi (192.168.1.4) I enter the following

```
ssh -L 127.0.0.1:3000:192.168.1.4:1234 user@192.168.1.4
```

I then started the server on that machine I want to connect to, tried to connect from the desktop machine

```
nrsc5 -H 127.0.0.1:3000 103.5 0
```

and it worked as expected

But I ultimately want to put the raspberry pi elsewhere and access it through the internet.  I have a dynamic DNS provider, so I substituted the pi's IP address, 192.168.1.4 with the name from the dynamic DNS

```
ssh -L 127.0.0.1:3000:machine.company.com:1234 user@machine.company.com
```

Then I start the server and try to connect from the desktop, only this time I get an error message.

```
channel 3: open failed: connect failed: Connection refused
```

Next I logged out, and logged in, only adding `-v`

```
ssh -v -L 127.0.0.1:3000:machine.company.com:1234 user@machine.company.com
```

Then, like before I started the server.
After trying `nrsc5` again, I get the following:

```
debug1: Connection to port 3000 forwarding to ladmo.asuscomm.com port 1234 requested.
debug1: channel 3: new [direct-tcpip]
channel 3: open failed: connect failed: Connection refused
debug1: channel 3: free: direct-tcpip: listening port 3000 for ladmo.asuscomm.com port 1234, connect from 127.0.0.1 port 44124 to 127.0.0.1 port 3000, nchannels 4
```

I opened port 1234 on the firewall.  Without messing with the tunnel, I tried `nrsc5 -H name.company.com:1234 103.5 0` and it worked.  It even worked when I logged into a VPN server in Australia on the desktop.

What am I doing wrong here?

Thank you

Comment: Maybe you should read again how the `-L` option in [ssh works](https://man.openbsd.org/ssh#L). The second IP is the host you connect to *from the remote host* and the first port (and optional IP) is the one you bind locally. So `ssh -L 3000:localhost:1234 user@machine.company.com` can be used to open a local port 3000 which is connected to 'local' port 1234 on host machine.company.com. With such a connection you can connect with `nrsc5 -H localhost:3000 ...`. The service on the remote machine doesn't even have to listen on the external interface.

Comment: Thank you for your reply.  I read the man page then tried ssh -L 3000:localhost:1234 user@machine.company.com In a terminal window on the desktop I entered nrsc5 -H localhost:3000 103.5 0 and I got:  Open remote device failed.  

I tried ssh -L 3000:192.168.1.4:1234 user@192.168.1.4. That got me logged in.  I started the server.  I then tried nrsc5 -H localhost:3000 103.5 0 and it worked.

Comment: @PaulPazderski  One more thing.  The raspberry pi only has one interface.  Both machines are  behind the same firewall.